# Why HOCR output does not work as expected for apache-tika

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

I'm trying to extract hocr text from a simple image [image: input]

1. Pure command line tesseract command works as expected
   `tesseract image_input.png out_hocr hocr`
2. When I m trying using tika-server (or tika-core) the output is just a text with extra new lines  `curl -T image_input.png http://localhost:9998/tika  --header "Content-type: image/png" --header "X-Tika-OCRenableImageProcessing: 1"  --header "X-Tika-OCRoutputType: hocr"` returns [image: output_tika]